# Kafka consumer group.id multiple messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have developed a Kafka consumer and there will be multiple instances of this consumer running in production.  I know how we can use group.id as to not duplicate the processing of data.  Is there a way to have all the consumers receive the message but send one consumer a leader bit?

Is there a way to have a group.id per topic or even per key in a topic?

Comment: why not to use diffent group ids for each consumer?

Comment: I want to have all of the consumers maintain the same records in their memory for a certain period of time.  When it's time, I want one of the consumers to submit their record to the database, but only one.  So it seems like the best route would to have no group.id for the messages, but then a group.id for the submit message.  That way only one consumer submits.  It's a unique business case and I am not sure there is an exact configuration I need.

Comment: Late comment: *submit their record to the database* -- This is what Kafka Connect is for, not sure why you'd do this in .NET client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this has nothing to with Kafka. You already know that by providing a unique group.id for each consumer, all consumer instances will get all messages from the topic. Now as far as the push to DB is concerned - you can factor out that logic and try using a `distributed lock` so that the push to DB part of your application can only be executed by one of the consumers. Is this a Java based setup ?

Comment: No it's .NET.  I'm using the confluent.kafka library.  The lock sounds like the way to go.